# dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace function error in dired -> emacs is looking for 'project--files-in-directory' which doesn't exist

Tags: dired

I have a problem with dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace in dired (by default mapped to 'Q'). I mark the applicable files as required, hit 'Q', enter my search and replacement strings and then get this error message:

Symbol’s function definition is void: project--files-in-directory

I've googled for this function to no avail. When I search for the function using C-h f, emacs tells me this is 'projectile-files-in-project-directory'.  So it would appear emacs can't find the function name it has created and so selects this function in projectile instead.

How do I debug this?  And/Or has anyone ever encountered this?

PS: I'm on Windows using both emacs v27.2 and v28.0.5

Comment: (1) What is your Emacs version? (2) Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: That's something I should have immediately thought of!  And no it doesn't happen when I use 'emacs -Q' which means that my init file is buggering something up.  Problem is that my init is a mess and huge.

Comment: Bisect your init file. You can use `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, etc. Delete the question, if you don't think the question is useful for others.

Comment: Okay - yes will have to figure this out and unless there's something genuinely valuable here, I'll answer my own question or just delete the entire post.   Thanks Drew.